# Is it possible to redirect a specific port to another IP/hostname? Webserver redirecting mail ports

Tags: linux, networking, amazon-web-services, nginx

So I have two separate Linux servers, one at server.com, with NGINX hosting a web server, and another at mail.server.com, hosting a mail server.

What I want to do is let people interact with my mail server by server.com:465 or server.com:993, these ports redirecting to mail.server:465 or mail.server:993. This will especially be useful when connecting via a mail client. (Thunderbird won't automatically try mail.server.com when adding user@server.com)

Idk if vhosts is right, I tried a normal vhost listening at 465/993 and redirecting URL but I don't think it worked. And I suspect it works purely under web-browsing circumstances and not like an smtp client trying to feel its way through.

I stumbled across something called stream, or stream proxy, and it looks like it could work. But of course it won't be installed by default and I have no idea how to compile or install applications on a Bitnami server (AWS Lightsail)...

Anything I've missed or understood wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ordinary Nginx vhosts won't work, because none of the mail protocols are anything like HTTP at all. The mail app doesn't send anything Nginx would understand, and it doesn't understand anything it receives from Nginx.

Besides that, most protocols other than HTTP don't actually have the concept of redirects, and neither does TCP itself.

Instead, your server might need to *relay all data* using something like haproxy, relayd, maybe even Nginx in TCP mode (which IIRC it has). The downside of this option is that the server won't be able to see clients' IP addresses, and you add another possible point of failure.

If that's not an option, you can try to find a way to make the app connect to the correct domain in the first place. Thunderbird actually has such a feature – you can host an [autoconfig](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Thunderbird/Autoconfiguration) file over HTTP, and the mail client will use it to determine the correct mail server name.

You can also try adding SRV records for `_imaps._tcp` and `_submission(s)._tcp` under your domain, pointing to the correct mail server. Some mail clients will use them for autoconfiguration when adding an account, though Thunderbird won't.

Comment: The part about an autoconfig file sounds reasonable. Would I host this on my HTTP webserver and include the information to my mail server? EDIT: yea looks like that, thanks for the tip

Comment: Another thing. Why does Thunderbird not look for the MX DNS record? I mean it sounds like it could be hellalot easier

Comment: MX specifies servers for _inbound_ mail. Thunderbird needs servers which handle _outbound_ mail. In small domains that's the same thing (same server providing both services on different TCP ports), but it is never guaranteed to be.

Comment: (The generic equivalent of MX for various other services, including IMAP and outbound mail submission, would be SRV records -- but so far [nobody has implemented that](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=342242).)